# What does Gmail's Method: users.labels.patch allow you to do, and how is that different from users.labels.update?

Tags: rest, google-api, gmail-api

The documentation simply says "Patch the specified label." What does that mean?

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/patch)

Answer (score 3):

A [label](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels#Label) object looks like this

```
JSON representation

{
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "messageListVisibility": enum (MessageListVisibility),
  "labelListVisibility": enum (LabelListVisibility),
  "type": enum (Type),
  "messagesTotal": integer,
  "messagesUnread": integer,
  "threadsTotal": integer,
  "threadsUnread": integer,
  "color": {
    object (Color)
  }
}
```

The HTTP request made to this method is a [PATCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb)

```
PATCH https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/labels/{id}
```

Which basically means that you do not need to send the full object with the request body only the parameters you send will be updated.  So if you just send Name the only the name will be updated on the label not the rest of the parameters.   This is a simplified request from update which used to require that the full object body be sent and anything not set would then be set to null or there would result in an error.